# Is this workflow possible with git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'd like to be able to do the following:

- Create a git branch off of a remote.
- Locally, create a new branch off of that local version of the remote.
- Do my dev work within that branch.
- Create a pull request from that branch into the original git remote.

  - At this point, the pull request can be reviewed, giving us a bit of a code review along the way.
- When that's okayed, pull that into the original remote.
- From there, sync that up with my svn trunk.

Is that possible with git-svn or something similar? I know that I can do a local git repo, do my own branching and such via git-svn, but I need that remote so that others can create pull-requests and such. Really just wanting a good code review solution and in the past, using just git, pull requests were a great way to go. Unfortunately we are using SVN at work, so we need to take that into consideration.

Thanks for any ideas on this :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're going through the same thing at work right now. We've looked at three approaches:

1. Home-grown setup based on the ideas in [this post](http://www.tfnico.com/presentations/git-and-subversion).
2. [SubGit](http://subgit.com/)
3. [Atlassian Stash + Subgit plugin](http://subgit.com/stash/)

We're already using in-house JIRA/GreenHopper instances extensively, and the first two solutions are too 'fiddly' for our liking, so we plan to try Stash + SubGit in the new year. (No affiliation, just been circling around solutions to this problem for awhile, and this one looks the most promising.)

So, to answer your question: the work flow you describe is certainly *possible* with `git-svn`, but... it may be more trouble than it's worth unless you have a very small team (three or four developers) who are all git *and* svn ninjas. For our 30-person team of very mixed backgrounds and skill sets, we just weren't comfortable trying to set up a transparent git-svn bridge on our own.

Answer (score 0):

I think git will serve your purpose, for code reviews you dont need to push the code to the remote repo followed by a pull, you can just generate a patch. The `patch` can then be sent to the code reviewer which has to just `apply patch` and review the code.